# Failed to execute with spring security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I get an error about spring security config that I can't solve. I'd appreciate it if you helped.

SecurityConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    private static final String USER = "USER";
    private static final String ADMIN = "ADMIN";


    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception{

        httpSecurity.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/","svc/v1/private/accounts/*").hasRole(USER).antMatchers("svc/v1/admin/accounts/*").hasAnyRole(ADMIN).and().formLogin(); 
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception{

        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("mutlu").password("mutlu123").and().withUser("admin").password("admin123").roles(ADMIN);

    }
}
```

Error Code

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot pass a null GrantedAuthority collection
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:198) ~[spring-core-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User.sortAuthorities(User.java:163) ~[spring-security-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User.<init>(User.java:123) ~[spring-security-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User$UserBuilder.build(User.java:535) ~[spring-security-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configurers.provisioning.UserDetailsManagerConfigurer$UserDetailsBuilder.build(UserDetailsManagerConfigurer.java:279) ~[spring-security-config-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configurers.provisioning.UserDetailsManagerConfigurer.initUserDetailsService(UserDetailsManagerConfigurer.java:60) ~[spring-security-config-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configurers.userdetails.UserDetailsServiceConfigurer.configure(UserDetailsServiceConfigurer.java:47) ~[spring-security-config-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configurers.userdetails.UserDetailsServiceConfigurer.configure(UserDetailsServiceConfigurer.java:34) ~[spring-security-config-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.configure(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:384) ~[spring-security-config-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.doBuild(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:330) ~[spring-security-config-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.build(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:41) ~[spring-security-config-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration.java:119) ~[spring-security-config-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.authenticationManager(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:269) ~[spring-security-config-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.getHttp(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:201) ~[spring-security-config-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.init(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:322) ~[spring-security-config-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.init(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:92) ~[spring-security-config-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at com.example.secure_service.Config.SecurityConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b345a0b9.init(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.init(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:371) ~[spring-security-config-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.doBuild(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:325) ~[spring-security-config-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.build(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:41) ~[spring-security-config-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.springSecurityFilterChain(WebSecurityConfiguration.java:104) ~[spring-security-config-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6333a9a9.CGLIB$springSecurityFilterChain$5(<generated>) ~[spring-security-config-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6333a9a9$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$9c07dd78.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-security-config-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) ~[spring-core-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:363) ~[spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6333a9a9.springSecurityFilterChain(<generated>) ~[spring-security-config-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    ... 22 common frames omitted

------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD FAILURE
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 5.941s
Finished at: Thu Jul 04 15:31:22 EEST 2019
Final Memory: 19M/225M
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.1.6.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on project secure_service: Could not exec java: Application finished with exit code: 1 -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

Comment: Kindly do not change your question. Firstly you posted with some Role related issue. Now you completely changed the question. Doing this, you are making answers for earlier question irrelevant.

Comment: Do not edit the question to [invalidate existing answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290704/3956566).

Comment: @YvetteColomb The edit you did in https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/56888111/5 hid the first line with the exception name and message because of a missing linebreak after the triple backticks. I fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot pass a null GrantedAuthority collection
```

The error is obvious, you should assign at least one role to your first user.
Assign Role as below :

> auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("mutlu").password("mutlu123").roles("USER")